# does this sentence have too many commas

Tags: commas

> As my confidence simultaneously dissipated, a teammate I had never spoken to, began chanting, soon followed by the rest of the team.

I'm just unsure because there are so many commas. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: thank you! but is my sentence grammatically incorrect?

Comment: could i instead write "As my confidence simultaneously dissipated, a teammate who I had never spoken to, began chanting, soon followed by the rest of the team"

Comment: The first comma is ok (.) Then it should continue like....a teammate, I had never spoken to, began chanting....,   The last comma clears it as  ...chanting, soon followed by.....else it may confuse, if it is 'chanting soon' or 'soon followed by...'

Comment: "As my confidence simultaneously dissipated, a teammate who I had never spoken to began chanting, soon followed by the rest of the team"  (remove the incorrect second comma; the remaining commas are necessary to preserve one particular meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should probably remove the comma between *to* and *began*.

Comment: It would help your answer and the OP to explain why the comma there is off.